# How to gitignore snapshot folders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, testing, jestjs

I am starting to learn more about Jest and testing such as snapshot testing. The way I have my components in react configured is...

```
- src
  - components
    - Component1
      - index.js
      - __tests__
        - Component1.test.js
        - __snapshots__
  - Component2
      - index.js
      - __tests__
        - Component2.test.js
        - __snapshots__
```

and so on.

I'm wondering what would be the line to write in my `.gitignore` to ignore the `__snapshots__` folder with this structure.

Currently I have this (which is wrong)

`/src/components/*/__snapshots__/`

Also, is it best to keep them in version control or to ignore them? I'd still like to know what I need to put in my `gitignore`, but would like to hear thoughts about this as well!

Thank you!

Comment: [Globbing Patterns](https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/usage/parameters/globbing-patterns)

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to have the snapshots version controlled? ["Commit snapshots and review them as part of your regular code review process. This means treating snapshots as you would any other type of test or code in your project."](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#1-treat-snapshots-as-code)

Comment: I think a line saying `__snapshots__` on the .gitignore at the root directory of the project should be enough.

Comment: Sounds like an anti-pattern to run the tests on your CI server based on snapshot data generated on each individual development machine, rather than make the CI server generate the snapshots and run tests. Not sure why the Jest team prefers this.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same question and ended up finding this post here. However, Jest documentation states that:

> all snapshot files should be committed alongside the modules they are
>   covering and their tests

Hope this helps others as has helped me.

Source: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html#should-snapshot-files-be-committed

Answer (score 11):

ignore the folder called **snapshots** anywhere, but not files with the same name

```
__snapshots__/
```

Since this has a “/” at the end only directories would be matched – removing it would also make the pattern catch files with the same name.

Comment: Snapshots ARE the tests. If you ignore the snapshots, you're 100% doing it wrong.

Comment: @fregante how is it related to the question? if you ask a question about ignoring garbage, you have one.

Comment: It's related because you probably should not directly answer a question that starts with "how much cyanide…". If you do, I'll leave the above comment explaining that _it's really best you do something else._